# .htaccess Regex Match File with Extensions or no Extension

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Basically I want to match any of the patterns below for the file path after the protocol through to the file name, even the file doesn't have an extension.

I almost got there, but once I try to make it match files without an extension, it matches until the rest of the line.

My test strings

```
http://regexr.com/foo.html?test (//regexr.com/foo.html)

http://regexr.com/foo?test      (//regexr.com/foo)

http://regexr.com/foo.php?test  (//regexr.com/foo.htm)

http://regexr.com/foo.htm?test  (//regexr.com/foo.htm)
```

My current expression is `\/(.+)\.php` but this doesn't match the second file path without the extension, and if I make the last collection optional, it selects through the GET parameters. Any help would be much appreciated.

---

**EDIT** Below is my .htaccess block that I'm attempting to modify

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)(\.php|\.html?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1.aspx [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*).aspx$ $1.php [QSA]
```

---

**FURTHER EDIT**
As pointed out, this may have been better asked as a redirect question. (Another note, I removed the html redirect since it causes a performance hit, so files with the extension `*.php` are the only files being redirected.)

These are how I would like to have the files handled; 301 redirecting to the new address and then continuing to be processed as PHP by the server as such:

```
http://regexr.com/foo.html (Doesn't redirect, not processed)
http://regexr.com/foo      (R to /foo.aspx, processed as /foo.php)
http://regexr.com/foo.php  (R to /foo.aspx, processed as /foo.php)
http://regexr.com/foo.htm  (Doesn't redirect, not processed)
http://regexr.com/foo.aspx (Doesn't redirect, processed as /foo.php)
```

Comment: Can you show your rules?

Comment: I can, not sure how this could help, but I will update my answer shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex pattern:

```
\s/([^?.]+)(?:\.php|\.html?)?[?\s]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jA9fO1/3)

---

Redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^?.]+)(?:\.php)?[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.aspx? [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.aspx$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: This still captures the GET parameters, which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Still can't get this to work, implementing this where I currently have `\/(.+)(\.php|\.html?)` makes no redirects at all happen. Also, your expression selects files with other extensions as well, causing a redirect loop since it will select `*.aspx` and redirect it to itself

Comment: That's why I asked you to clarify what redirect you're attempting. It is far easier to answer rewrite issues rather than a generic regex issue. For all 4 URLs you showed above if you can show what those should be redirected to then I will provide your a redirect solution rather than a regex solution.

Comment: Do you want to capture `foo` in all 4 cases? If yes then check my updated answer and new demo.

Comment: I updated my answer to further clarify, but I'm about to test your current regex to see if that works

Comment: Sadly, this still does not redirect the files with no extensions, thanks for being so patient with me however, very much appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74274/discussion-between-anubhava-and-brian-leishman).

Comment: Even after your edit it is not clear where those URLs should be redirected.